# Converting dimensions in power spectral density

Tags: spectral-density

I want to convert my data which is in `Vpp/sqrt(Hz)` to `rad^2/sqrt(Hz)` to compare with other data. So that I can go forward in my research work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if this is a particular coding question or EE/Math question?  What have you tried?

Comment: we have a simulated PSD in matlab with units of rad^2/sqrt(Hz). We have seen a PSD in spectrum analyzer in the units Vpp/sqrt(Hz). Now we want to compare both of these in order to get some noise modelling out of it.